# Can "is" be used for plural?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

"The only thing bringing any money into that floating city IS tourists"

Is this grammatically correct? Is there ever a time when one could us "is" for a plural?

Comment: 'Thing' is singular, not plural.

Comment: ... is tourism.